# JavaFX - move window with effect

Tags: javafx-8

I have undecorated non-fullscreen window, which I like to move outside screen boundaries when mouse leaves it's area, but do so smoothly. I found some JavaFX functionality to do so - Timeline, but KeyValue for that Timeline doesn't supports stage.xProperty - because this property is readonlyProperty. Is there way to move my window smoothly using JavaFX functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shaking Stage in javaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634960/shaking-stage-in-javafx)

Comment: Actually, though the technique involved is somewhat similar, the current answers to the shaking stage question aren't all that great for your purposes as they don't smoothly move the stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup proxy properties that you manipulate via KeyValues in a Timeline.  A listener on the proxy can modify the actual stage location.

[image: window]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class StageSwiper extends Application {

    private static final int W = 350;
    private static final Duration DURATION = Duration.seconds(0.5);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label instructions = new Label(
            "Window will slide off-screen when the mouse exits it.\n" +
                    "Click the window to close the application."
        );
        instructions.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        final StackPane root = new StackPane(instructions);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");

        DoubleProperty stageX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        stageX.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null && newValue.doubleValue() != Double.NaN) {
                stage.setX(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });

        final Timeline slideLeft = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        DURATION,
                        new KeyValue(
                                stageX,
                                -W,
                                Interpolator.EASE_BOTH
                        )
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        DURATION.multiply(2)
                )
        );
        slideLeft.setOnFinished(event -> {
            slideLeft.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stageX.setValue(stage.getX());
        });

        root.setOnMouseClicked(event -> Platform.exit());
        root.setOnMouseExited(event -> slideLeft.play());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, W, 100, Color.BURLYWOOD));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();

        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stageX.set(stage.getX());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, it works fine! Now I will try to embed this solution to my project.